# how to validate my login id which might be phone or email using Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

for my login screen, User can login by using his email or phone number. Here i am using jquery validation plugin.
Below is my code :

```
  $('.login-form').validate({

        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        rules: {
            username: {
                required:true,
                phoneUS:function(){
                  var a =document.getElementById("Username").value;
                  console.log(a);
                  var filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
                var r= filter.test(a);
                console.log(filter.test(a)==true);

                if(filter.test(a)==true)
                {
                  return true;
                }
                  return false;


                },
                email:function()
                {
                    var a =document.getElementById("Username").value;
                  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                    var re= regex.test(a);
                    console.log(regex.test(a)==true);
                    if(regex.test(a)==true){
                      return true;
                    }return false;
                }
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            },
            remember: {
                required: false
            }
        },

        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Username is required."
            },
            password: {
                required: "Password is required."
            }
        },
```

if i enter email still its asks for phone number and vise versa, my requirement is if i enter email it should validate for correct email format not for phone and same in case of phone, Can any help me out